# Time displaying in a date only field from SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a date field in a SQL table coming in to a `DataGridView` in c#. But for some reason, it comes with a time too, even though its just a date field.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Keep your DateTime object as a DateTime. The DataGridView offers a format string property where you can format your DateTime object as you wish.

This will get you started on formatting dates - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As part of your Data Binding object for the `DataGridView` make the property a `string`.

```
public class DataBindingObj
{
    public string DateRemoved { get; set; }
}
```

Use [`DateTime.ToShortDateString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx).

This will return the culture specific formatting (`M/d/yyyy` for en-US).

```
var bindingObjs = new List<DataBindingObj>();

foreach(var obj in dataFromDatabase)
{
    var bindingObj = new DataBindingObj { DateRemoved = obj.DateRemoved.ToShortDateString() };
    bindingObjs.Add(bindingObj);
}

dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingObjs;
```

Edit: From the comments it seems DataGridView has a property for that:

```
public class DataBindingObj
{
    public DateTime DateRemoved { get; set; }
}

dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingObjs;
dataGridView1.Columns["DateRemoved"].Format = "d";
```

Comment: There is no need to make the property a string. You will have more control of it as a DateTime object. The DataGridView has a property to set a format string. setting it to 'd' will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

in case you want it in any specific [format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) Do it like this

```
 string format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
 string dateOnly = dt.ToString(format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

and in case your database is returning string you have to do this as well

```
 DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(yourDateTimeString, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

12:00:00 AM is the default time for `DATETIME` types in C# if time is not specified.

To get only the date use `dateTime.ToShortDateString()`